# Convert a multiband raster to an animation format

Tags: python, raster, rasterio

Note: I previously posted this question on stackoverflow (https://stackoverflow.com/q/70174165/10360134) but I think SO-GIS is a better place. How should I proceed to avoid duplicates (is migrating questions possible)?

### Problem description:

I want to take a raster multiband, where each band becomes a frame of an animation. I also want a colorbar giving the color scaling, and longitude/latitude axis.

### Solution:

From different sources, I could put that script together:

```
import rasterio.plot
from rasterio.plot import show_hist
from matplotlib import pyplot
import imageio
from tqdm import tqdm     # progress bar
import numpy

def animate(inputRaster, output='animation.gif'):

source = rasterio.open(inputRaster)

with imageio.get_writer(output, mode='I') as writer:

    for bandId in tqdm(range(source.count)):

        bandId = bandId+1
        band = source.read(bandId, masked=True)

        fig, ax = pyplot.subplots()

        # to get longitude/latitude axis
        extent = numpy.asarray(source.bounds)[[0,2,1,3]]

        # use imshow so that we have something to map the colorbar to
        image_hidden = ax.imshow(band,
                                 extent=extent,
                                 cmap='viridis',
                                 vmin=0,
                                 vmax=100)

        # plot on the same axis with rio.plot.show
        image = rasterio.plot.show(band,
                              transform=source.transform,
                              ax=ax,
                              cmap='viridis',
                              vmin=0,
                              vmax=100)

        # add colorbar using the now hidden image
        fig.colorbar(image_hidden, ax=ax)

        pyplot.savefig("layer.png", bbox_inches='tight')
        pyplot.close()

        image = imageio.imread('layer.png')
        writer.append_data(image)
```

### Output

This gives me a nice output, that gets automatically converted according to the output format passed as an argument.

[image: animation]

### Residual problem

However it is painfully slow, I guess because I spend my time writing png files.

Do I really need to save the plot as a `png` file before to append it to the `writer` object? I tried to give it the entire plot, this raises a bunch of exceptions.

I also receive this warning when generating mp4 files: `Warning: data is not aligned! This can lead to a speed loss`

Comment: It seems you just need to pass a numpy array to the writer, so the png should be unnecessary if you can [go straight from matplotlib to numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7821917/6179432)

Comment: @mikewatt OMG yes it's so much faster :) Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So as advised by @mikewatt, I ended up passing a numpy array to matplotlib.
This leads to a much faster conversion.
The code is below (I left three different plotting solutions that were benchmarked here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/67823421/10360134

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from optparse import OptionParser
import io
import rasterio.plot
from rasterio.plot import show_hist

from matplotlib import pyplot
import imageio
from tqdm import tqdm
import numpy

def plot1(fig):
    fig.canvas.draw()
    data = numpy.frombuffer(fig.canvas.tostring_rgb(), dtype=numpy.uint8)
    w, h = fig.canvas.get_width_height()
    im = data.reshape((int(h), int(w), -1))
    return(im)


def plot2(fig):
    with io.BytesIO() as buff:
        fig.savefig(buff, format='png')
        buff.seek(0)
        im = plt.imread(buff)
        return(im)


def plot3(fig):
    with io.BytesIO() as buff:
        fig.savefig(buff, format='raw')
        buff.seek(0)
        data = numpy.frombuffer(buff.getvalue(), dtype=numpy.uint8)
    w, h = fig.canvas.get_width_height()
    im = data.reshape((int(h), int(w), -1))
    return(im)


def get_global_max(source):

    array = source.read()
    # mask off no data values
    m = (array != source.nodata)
    return array[m].max()


def animate(inputRaster, vmax=None, output='animation.gif'):

    source = rasterio.open(inputRaster)

    if vmax is None:
        vmax = get_global_max(source)

    with imageio.get_writer(output, mode='I') as writer:

        for bandId in tqdm(range(source.count)):

            bandId = bandId+1
            band = source.read(bandId, masked=True)

            fig, ax = pyplot.subplots()

            # to get longitude/latitude axis
            extent = numpy.asarray(source.bounds)[[0,2,1,3]]

            # use imshow so that we have something to map the colorbar to
            image_hidden = ax.imshow(band,
                                     extent=extent,
                                     cmap='viridis',
                                     vmin=0,
                                     vmax=vmax)

            # plot on the same axis with rio.plot.show
            image = rasterio.plot.show(band,
                                  transform=source.transform,
                                  ax=ax,
                                  cmap='viridis',
                                  vmin=0,
                                  vmax=vmax)

            # add colorbar using the now hidden image
            fig.colorbar(image_hidden, ax=ax)

            writer.append_data(plot3(fig))
            pyplot.close()


def main(argv):
    parser = OptionParser()
    parser.add_option("-i", "--input", type="str", dest="input", help="Geotiff multiband file")
    parser.add_option("-o", "--output", type="str", dest="output", help="output animation name")
    parser.add_option("-m", "--vmax", type="int", dest="vmax", help="max value in color scale")
    (options, args) = parser.parse_args(argv)
    return animate(options.input, options.vmax, options.output)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

The script can be called with:

- `python3 animate.py --input "animation.tif"` (defaults)
- `python3 animate.py --input "animation.tif" --output "animation.mp4"` (changes output format)
- `python3 animate.py --input "animation.tif" --vmax 100` (changes the colorbar max values, if none is given then vmax is inferred from the raster data.
- or a combination of those